# Convert dictionary to list of values, sorted by keys

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a dictionary

```
d = {
     date_3:  val_3,
     date_1:  val_1,
     date_2:  val_2,
}
```

I want to convert this to a list, sorted by the dictionary keys:

```
l = [val_1,
     val_2,
     val_3
]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you a list of values, sorted by key.

```
l = [d[k] for k in sorted(d)]
```

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
l = sorted(d.keys())
l = [d[u] for u in l]
print l
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get values using `dict.keys()` and you can sort it using `list.sort()`

```
values = d.keys()
values.sort()
[d[x] for x in values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as ,

```
[i[1] for i in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda s: s[0])]
```

Comment: That gives a list sorted by value. The op wants the list to be sorted by the key.

Comment: That looks correct now, so I've removed the downvote. I think @Ikke's answer is easier to understand.